# Naive Bayes in R - Dealing with feature vectors of all 0s given a class

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am currently using the klaR package for the Naive Bayes implementation.

My features are a document term frequency matrix of a corpus, e.g.:

```
thank first kit less
1     2     4   3
```

and am doing binary classification with their frequencies.

Running: 
    classifier <- NaiveBayes(as.matrix(dtm.train.nb)
    as.factor(text.train$Label), laplace = 3)

yields an error message of "Zero variances for at least one class in variables" and feel like this is due to one class having a feature of all zeros, aka a feature never appears in one of my classes. So to clarify I have, for one class:

```
thank first kit less
0     3     2   1
0     2     1   8  
0     6     5   3
0     12    1   2
```

where here thank never appears in one of my classes.
How can I smooth my data so I don't get probabilities of 0 for the unseen feature? The Laplace smoothing does not seem to be working in this context.

```
library(klaR)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
text <- read.csv('cleanedtrain.csv')
colnames(text) <- c('Label', 'Text')
text$Label <- as.factor(text$Label)
text$Text <- as.character(text$Text)
text <- text[sample(nrow(text)),]
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text$Text))

corpus.clean <- corpus %>%
  tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
  tm_map(removeWords, stopwords(kind="en")) %>%
  tm_map(stripWhitespace)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.clean)
inspect(dtm)

text.train <- text[1:44,]
text.test <- text[45:58,]

dtm.train <- dtm[1:44,]
dtm.test <- dtm[45:58,]

corpus.clean.train <- corpus.clean[1:44]
corpus.clean.test <- corpus.clean[45:58]

freqTerms <- findFreqTerms(dtm.train, 3)
dtm.train.nb <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.clean.train, control =     list(dictionary = freqTerms))
dtm.test.nb <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.clean.test, control = list(dictionary = freqTerms))

classifier <- NaiveBayes(as.matrix(dtm.train.nb),     as.factor(text.train$Label), usekernel = T, fL = 1)
pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=as.matrix(dtm.test))
```

dtm.train.nb Data:

```
Docs better cool can dont get like need mouse mouses say
14      0      0   0    1   1    1    0    2     2   0
16      0      2   0    1   0    0    0    2     1   0
20      0      2   0    0   0    0    0    0     0   0
23      0      0   0    1   3    1    0    2     0   1
27      4      0   3    2   4    2    2    0     0   5
32      0      0   0    0   0    0    0    2     0   0
33      0      1   0    1   0    1    1    0     0   0
34      0      0   6    4   0    2    3    1     1   2
40      1      1   0    1   0    0    1    0     0   1
8       1      7   1    1   1    3    2    1     5   0
```

label data text.train$Label:

```
[1] TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 
FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
[29] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: If `thank` is categorical, then set as a factor with any additional levels ie `dat$thank = factor(dat$thank, levels=0:1)` even if not present in the data. If its numeric you can estimate using the density `usekernel=TRUE` . of course, you need strong  a priori beliefs to do this rather than dropping the variable , which is basically a constant so not adding any info.

Comment: @user20650 is there a way to do smoothing (laplace smoothing) within the Naive Bayes function so that 0 probability values do not occur?

Comment: yes, see`?klaR:::NaiveBayes`, particularily the `fL` argument

Comment: @user20650 changing the fL argument to a nonzero value still yields the same error! thank is a numerical value, the frequencies of the occurance of "thank" in that document

Comment: I created a wee example here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146796/sammuh . Can you try to show your issue please.

Comment: @user20650 I cannot reply because I haven't reached that much karma yet haha. I tried using the kernel and fL and still recieved error:

extra argument �fl� will be disregardedIn density.default(xx, ...) :

and in prediction, Error in 1:nattribs : argument of length 0

Comment: hah, okay. Can you show you r code that produced that error please - edit:: use fL (big L) not fl (small l)

Comment: @user20650 code is provided! I know how to do this in python but would like to learn in R. I already have a document term matrix, but during the calculations of class probabilities I wish there was a way to do in R where you can do laplace smoothing on the variables to avoid the situation where if the P(word|class) is 0!

Comment: Thanks, are you able to share your data: dtm.train.nb and text.train$Label : enough to reproduce your error. (dont need to see how you produced the data ;P)

Comment: @user20650 hope that helps paint a better picture

Comment: Thank yo: please see the chat room. This additional data did not throw an error, so its hard to suggest what to do. I am assuming it is something within the data themselves (to do with zero counts / variance across the grouping levels) but can you see if you can add enough data to reproduce. (ps you can do this with `dput(dtm.train.nb)` so its easier to copy and paste)